# Does a card like Languish count as a damage-dealing sorcery?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was thinking of using [Mark of Asylum](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mark%20of%20Asylum) to protect my creatures from cards like [Languish](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Languish), but does giving all creatures -4/-4 count as damage dealt in the same way, for instance, [Swirling Sandstorm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Swirling%20Sandstorm) does?

Answer (score 5):

No, only spells and abilities that actually say damage deal damage. (Creatures can also deal damage in combat or when fighting, of course.) Languish just changes power and toughness.

Comment: And things were "damage" is in the rules for the thing, like combat and fight.

Comment: Also, damage causes life loss; but life loss isn't damage!